# Does a user need to be logged in on Facebook to share an open-graph story through Facebook Messenger?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

For a user to be able to message an open-graph story via the new Facebook Messenger functionality (messaging an open graph message), does the user need to be logged in to Facebook in my app?

I am talking about the new functionality presented by Facebook at their f8 conference (sending an open graph story to friends through Facebook Messenger).

I'm pretty sure I have everything set up correctly in my mobile app. But the problem is that the other testers (people registered as testers in my app on Facebook) are receiving the open graph story correctly, but when tapping on the open graph story, even though Facebook Messenger redirects to the right app (my app), the FBAppCall object doesn't contain any targetURL information, there is no `&target_url=....` ...even though my open graph object has a proper URL set.

That is why I am thinking: Does the user need to also POST the open-graph the story somewhere (thus the user needs to be logged in with Facebook), in order for Facebook Messenger to be able to get the object's URL later?

It seems like this shouldn't be the case, as opening this new functionality of sharing through messenger should be just about getting rid that friction when sharing a story.

Answer (score 1):

> does the user need to be logged in to Facebook?

No, he doesn't.

> does the user need to be logged in to Facebook in my app?

You must have a valid client token, which means your user must have authorized your app. Just once. Then he can log out from Facebook and/or your app, and you can keep the token on your database and make as many requests as you want, regardless of the user being logged in anywhere.

That means: After the user logs out from facebook, you still get to keep the client token for as long as you want (Well, they do expire: take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ for more info), and use it to make requests on behalf of the user as you please, using any of the permissions your app was granted by the user (read messages, send messages, post on my behalf, etc.).

In order to share an open graph story through facebook messenger, there must be a story to share published somewhere, of course.

Take on account privacy settings may prevent user/app A from seeing a user/app B story shared by someone else (user/app C) if user/app A didn't have permission to see the original post in the first place (happens when posting with 'only to friends' privacy setting, for example)

The best you can do: debug the responses your app is getting from Facebook. Every time something unusual occurs Facebook will notify you. Are you sure you are not getting any errors/warning messages?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, if this is the case, then it makes sense: I never ask the user to log in using Facebook or demand rights to his wall etc., therefore I have no token from FB. But if this is the case, the whole situation is very counterintuitive, because I can't understand why would a user need to POST a story that he just wants to share with a couple of his friends (chosen from Facebook Messenger)

Comment: Well a post is a post. Privacy settings allow a custom list of friends to share it with, but it doesn't notify those friends with a message (Although it'll most probably show up on their newsfeed). You use the message as a means of simultaneous multiple notification, and the message will have either a link to the post or the embedded post (I haven't used this functionality yet, so I'm not sure which is it).

Comment: Anyway, I'm pretty sure without a token you can't do anything: You need a session in order to send a request (except an auth request) and you need a token (or a valid 1 use auth redirect callback code) in order to produce a session.

Comment: By the way: all recent facebook SDKs are built on top of their Oauth 2.0 implementation. (You can even build your own SDK as it's encouraged for windows 8 apps, for example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0) If you want to know more about Oauth 2.0 here is the specs doc: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749